# Not hosted OpenX + Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, ads, openx

I have an own OpenX server, serving ads in my websites.
Now, I'm thinking of creating a FB app and want to add ads to it. I want to know if I can put my own ads on the app or I need to use one of the advertiser list here: https://developers.facebook.com/adproviders/

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** use your own advertising network **inside** of your app canvas, provided you follow [Facebook's guidelines](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/).

You **cannot** use it to control what ads Facebook displays alongside your app, to the right, in Facebook's ad designated area.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your own adserver as long as your ads dont breach the developer policy agreement you accepted when signing up for the developer program.

Answer (score 0):

You can serve the ads via [OpenX Source Ad Server](http://www.revive-adserver.com) to Facebook APPs (Inside your).

Also You can serve targeted ads to App users (based on App settings)